# Updating SQL using another table using Python

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to update the Cost column in my sample table using another table.  Right now it's updating the cost but only using the value from one cell my test table (120).  I'm trying to figure out this line of code:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE sample set Cost = (select test.Cost from sample join test where test.City = sample.city) WHERE EXISTS (select test.City, sample.City from test join sample where test.City = sample.City)''')
```

My results:

```
[('Hamilton', 'Grand Caymen', 120.0),
 ('Hong Kong', 'China', 120.0),
 ('Dubai', 'Arab Emirates', 120.0)]
```

I'm trying to get:

```
[('Hamilton', 'Grand Caymen', 120.0),
 ('Hong Kong', 'China', 90.0),
 ('Dubai', 'Arab Emirates', 500.0)]
```

My whole code is below

---

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('testdb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('drop table if exists test')
c.execute('create table test (Country text, City text, Cost real)')
x = [['Hamilton', 'Grand Caymen', 120], ['Hong Kong', 'China', 90], ['Dubai', 'Arab Emirates', 500]]
c.executemany('insert into test (Country, City, Cost) values (?, ?, ?)', x)

c.execute('drop table if exists sample')
c.execute('create table sample (Country text, City text, Cost real)')
x = [['Hamilton', 'Grand Caymen'], ['Hong Kong', 'China'], ['Dubai', 'Arab Emirates']]
c.executemany('insert into sample (Country, City) values (?, ?)', x)

c.execute('''UPDATE sample set Cost = (select test.Cost from sample join test where test.City = sample.city) WHERE EXISTS (select test.City, sample.City from test join sample where test.City = sample.City)''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query to update the statement is picking up the first value only. Below query would update each city with it's respective cost. This syntax is for mysql.

```
UPDATE
    Sample s,
    test t
SET
    s.cost = t.cost
WHERE
    s.city = t.city;
```

so your final query would be

```
c.execute('''UPDATE Sample s, test t SET s.cost = t.cost WHERE s.city = t.city;''')
```

**Example**

Test table

```
+-----------+---------------+-----+
| Hamilton  | Grand Caymen  | 120 |
| Hong Kong | China         |  90 |
| Dubai     | Arab Emirates | 500 |
+-----------+---------------+-----+
```

Sample table

```
+-----------+---------------+--+
| Hamilton  | Grand Caymen  |  |
| Hong Kong | Chin          |  |
| Dubai     | Arab Emirates |  |
+-----------+---------------+--+
```

After running the query

```
+-----------+---------------+-----+
| Hamilton  | Grand Caymen  | 120 |
| Hong Kong | China         |  90 |
| Dubai     | Arab Emirates | 500 |
+-----------+---------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Because *sample* is reused in subquery there is no correlated query to outer level. Consider removing *sample* inside subquery:

```
sql = '''UPDATE sample 
         SET Cost = (select test.Cost
                     from test 
                     where test.City = sample.city) 
         WHERE EXISTS
             (select 1 from test
              where test.City = sample.City)
      '''
c.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```